A movie about police officer infiltrating soccer fans
Please help identify a 1970s-1990s British movie.
A police officer is delegated to infiltrate a soccer hooligans. He is very skeptic, but soon becomes one of them and begins to protect them. There is a conflict between loyalty to his new  friends and the duty. He became fanatic and it's hard to tell if he's doing this to get trusted or just for pleasure.
I remember fans were meeting in some pub and the main character had an affair with the female bartender.
I don't remember how this exactly ends, but I think it was that the fans group is destroyed by the police. The main character is awarded for being very secret and a good actor, his bosses think he was just playing to be real, but he was real. At the very ending it is shown that he is now infiltrating new-fasist organization (doing Nazi salute) and it is left for the audience to guess if he's doing his new task or he did become a fanatic nazi.
I was sure one of the minor characters was played by Pete Postlethwaite, but nothing in his filmography matches.

Possibly "I.D." aka "Undercover" (1994/1995) directed by Philip Davis. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID_(film) and/or http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113375/

Ah - you beat me to it!  An awesome film.

Thanks. I can't verify this at the moment, but I think this is the movie.

I remember this 'movie' very well as it was shown at the Toronto International Film Festival. I believe that it was originally a 3 X part BBC television series and I thought that the main character was played by the well known actor Robert Carlye but I can not find it in his filmography. In the series, a police officer, who cared nothing at all about football, infiltrates the local fan club of a small town English league football team and becomes completely immersed and carried away by the mob mentality subculture of the local supporters club. His police superiors lose complete control over him, can not get him back 'from the field' and eventually 'out' him to the local football supporters club in order to put an end to the operation. This finishes his involvement with the local club and in the last scene of the film he is seen marching as a skinhead in a white supremacist's parade. The film's genesis apparently sprang from an eventually disproven theory that Scotland Yard had formulated, thinking that soccer hooliganism was being orchestrated by the Mafia in order to cause chaos in the 'system'.

Do you remember the Festival date?
